# MySQL Query or Excel 2010 - Which is the better way of arranging data for reports?

Tags: mysql, excel, excel-2010

**Info:**  Server version: 5.1.39  - MySQL / phpMyAdmin
**Php:**  5.4
**Server:**  Apache
**Code is run via:** Server SQL Query (copy & paste in the phpMyAdmin) or in MySQL Workbench or using a custom shopping cart manager.
**Exports to:** Excel 2010 (.csv then to .xlsx for sales reports)

Hi there,
This is more a personal question, rather than a technical, however the answer should have a technical component.

Which is better?  Run a full query (with calculations) in MySQL, export to Excel and work on that data OR Run a basic query and then run the calculations in Excel?

**The scenario:**
My sales reports are in MySQL from my online store, each month I export the data that I need and create reports in Excel with additional information.  (Info not in the store).
My query has calculations, both for profit/loss & dates.  I can do this in excel as well.

I am not an expert in either field, barely scraping by with help from people such as the community here and other sites, however I'd like to read some feedback from those that work with both.

I currently use things like (in addition to column calculations):

```
DATE_FORMAT(T5.date_purchased, '%Y-%m-%b') As OrdMonth,  
DATE_FORMAT(T5.date_purchased + INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-%b') As PayMonth,  
concat(date_format(T5.date_purchased + INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%y%m'), '-', T4.manufacturers_id) As RepID,  
DATE_FORMAT(T5.date_purchased + INTERVAL 1 MONTH,'%y%m') As BatchID,
```

Which I can do in Excel with similar formulas.

So, is it better to have the report generate from the server as I want it in Excel, or just get the barest of info & run the calculations after?

Thank you in advance for your knowledge & input.

Answer (score 0):

If the target user is any typical viewer of a web page, then use PHP+SQL.

If the target user is you, then get the data out as quickly as you can, then massage it with Excel.

Excel is more flexible, and functions + VBA will take you farther and faster than SQL.

In order to go more in depth with the answer I need more details.

EDIT

Here is the solution that I use very often: it is not professional, but when it's for personal use it's the fastest way:

- Open both the csv file with the data to analyze and the Excel file with a VBA macro called CreateReport.xmls
- Run the macro

Here is the description of the steps executed by the macro:

- Scan all the open workbooks looking for the csv file (recognizing it for example by some header that is always there)
- Add columns with formulas
- For each report:

  - Duplicate the sheet
  - Delete the rows or columns that you don't need
  - Apply the formatting

If you don't know VBA there are many resources out there to get started. You can come back here when you have more specific questions.

Comment: thank you. It's just for me, as my note above I run it in the SQL Query either direct in PHP MyAdmin or through MySQL Workbench, I don't use PHP at all, it's a simple .sql/.txt copy & paste and out pops my csv, pre-calculated ready for my post-export work in excel.  In excel book I have things like exchange rates, other store sales figures etc & bank fees/charges which aren't captured at the time of sale.  I've been considering creating a new table and injecting the external data in monthly to have it consolidated on the server, but don't know how to, that's a paid job I think.